# C++ DP solution to LeetCode #377, does this code have a bug?

Tags: c++, c++11

This C++ solution is a direct translation of the [top voted Java solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/discuss/85036/1ms-Java-DP-Solution-with-Detailed-Explanation) in the discussion forum. My own G++ compiler compiles and runs it just fine with this test case however the LeetCode submission would yield an error (please have a quick try).

I would think memory is initialized properly and bounds checks are in place. What could be the problem?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int combinationSum4(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> dp(target + 1, 0);
        dp[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < dp.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++) {
                if (i - nums[j] >= 0) {
                    dp[i] += dp[i - nums[j]];
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[target];
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> nums {
        3, 33, 333,
    };
    cout << Solution().combinationSum4(nums, 10000) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Test case:

```
[3,33,333]
10000
```

Error message:

```
Line 9: Char 17: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 357856184 + 1941940377 cannot be represented in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
```

Comment: The more interesting question is why the Java implementation does not show this error.

Comment: I actually think this code is correct. Could the LC judge have a bug?

Comment: I copied this code, added headers and some output.  Even with a `long long`, this overflows at `dp[792]`.  However, with that `nums` array, only every 3rd element of `dp` will have a nonzero value, `dp[10000]` will be zero.

Comment: dp[10000] = 0 is the correct answer.

Comment: No the memory is not corrupted. There is no possibility in the code.

Comment: Using doubles, `dp[9999] = 2.57895e+244` (approximately).

Comment: Okay I think I haven't fully understood the algorithm itself.

Comment: I posted a work-around as a second answer.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I posted a work-around below.

Answer (score 2):

The message shows the error clearly. 357856184 + 1941940377 = 2299796561 which is bigger than a 32 bit int max -> 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647.

In C++ standard, there is no guarantee for the size of int. So to be safe, you can use int64_t, according to C++ 11.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: I understand. I just don't see how this is possible given the simple test case. If I change vector<int> to vector<long> there is still an error.

Comment: As you can see even the largest number in the array 333 is repeated 10000 time, it's still smaller than MAX_INT.

Comment: Sorry I just double checked, long sometimes default to 32 bits as well. So I changed my answer. It is better to use int64_t.

Comment: I did not read your algorism. If you are pretty sure that the number should not exceed max int, then it sounds like there is something wrong in your algorism.

Comment: On LeetCode long == int64_t.

Comment: Here we go. Also I quickly read your code, it seems the last item in your nums will be added more than 10000 times.

Comment: I think your algorism has some issue. I added 
cout << "dp[" << i << "] = " << dp[i] << endl; in the loop
Here is last line output for target = 300
From the result, you can see it has been accumulated and result is lot more than 100 * 33
dp[300] = 8664546

Comment: By changing vector<int> to vector<long> and bound dp[i] in the inner loop I was able to submit this solution to LeetCode.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm is correct but flawed. It doesn't handle integer overflow during the calculation. An improved solution is as follows:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int combinationSum4(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<long> dp(target + 1, 0);
        dp[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < dp.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++) {
                if (i - nums[j] >= 0) {
                    dp[i] += dp[i - nums[j]];
                    dp[i] %= numeric_limits<int>::max();
                }
            }
        }
        return dp[target];
    }
};
```